# Closed form for solution of $t_{n+1}=t_n(t_n-2)$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

As in the title I am interested in finding closed form for sequence satysfing $$t_{n+1}=t_n(t_n-2)$$ with $t_1=4$. I have tried many guesses, because I don't know if there is a metod to solve that, but without succes.

Comment: Your recurrence location is similar to a [logistic map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_map), so I don't think there is a way to find a closed form for its solutions.

Comment: @A.P.: there are some very special cases of the logistic map that are solvable in closed form. This is one of them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By setting $t_n=a_n+1$ we have:
$$ a_{n+1} = a_n^2-2 \tag{1}$$
then by setting $a_n=2b_n$ we have:
$$ b_{n+1} = 2 b_n^2-1 \tag{2} $$
It is not difficult to recognize the duplication formula for the (hyperbolic) cosine.

In particular, assuming $b_0=\cosh t_0$, $b_n = \cosh(2^n t_0)$ follows by induction.

Since in our case $b_1=\frac{3}{2}$ gives $b_0=\frac{\sqrt{5}}{2}$, we have $t_0=\log\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)=\log\phi$, hence:

> $$ t_n = 1+2\cosh(2^n \log\phi) = 1+\left(\phi^{2^n}+\phi^{-2^n}\right)=1+L_{2^n}\tag{3} $$

where $L_m$ is the $m$-th [Lucas number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas_number).

Comment: very, very, very ;) nice. What is even more funny I've started from (1) and fought that my transform is clever...

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**: prove by induction that:
$$t_n=\alpha^{2^n}+\alpha^{-2^n}+1 $$

with $\alpha$ is one of the roots of $x+\frac{1}{x}=3$

Comment: Now it's explained in the first answer, but the idea is the following:$$ \left(x^{2^n}+\frac{1}{x^{2^n}}\right)^2=x^{2^{n+1}}+\frac{1}{x^{2^{n+1}}}+2 $$ and from this one can deduce a genral form for a sequence which verifies $x_{n+1}=x_n^2-2$, and we know that $(t_{n+1}-1)=(t_{n}-1)^2-2$, by the way $\alpha= \frac{3\mp \sqrt{5}}{2}$

Comment: Thanks, that explains it a little more.